# Cookies are set in local but not in production

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm using React + Next js on the frontend, Node.JS Express on the backend. While working on localhost, I was able to set cookies in backend response. But when I moved it to digitalocean, I could not perform this operation. I am working on the same server, two different ports and the same domain, but the cookies are not set.

Backend response

```
  res.cookie("auth-token", result.token + ';', {
            secure: true,
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)),
            sameSite: "none",
            domain: ".xxxx.com"
        }).cookie("username", result.username + ';', {
            secure: true,
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)),
            sameSite: "none",
            domain: ".xxxx.com"
        }).send(new BaseResponse(result, true));
```

Set cookies are being set but there is no record in the cookies section.
Also FE side, i am using {withCrediantials:true} for request with axios

```
 axios.post(`${AppConstants.REST_PROVIDER}/login`, {
            code: code,
            password: password
        }, { withCredentials: true }).then(d => {
```

Cookie permissions granted on Chrome. I tried everything but failed. Can you help with why it works on localhost and does not work on the domain on the server?

---

I solved the problem, if you want to set cookies with domain, don't use port. If you are not in https, do not use secure. If you are using a sub domain use, "." sign before the set cookie domain value (.xyz.com).

Comment: Does your backend and frontend use the same domain?

Comment: Yes they use same domain, different ports

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem, if you want to set cookies with domain, don't use port. If you are not in https, do not use secure. If you are using a sub domain use, "." sign before the set cookie domain value (.xyz.com).

Comment: having the same issue - can you provide a code example?

Comment: what for different domains?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass option to the cookie while sending in response , please make sure if your backend is on https , add secure=true option in cookie option . That's work for me

```
const options = {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        overwrite:true,
  
      };

res.cookie("token", token, options)
```